# systeminfo command does not run on WIN XP Home Turkish

Tags: windows, windows-xp, turkish

I am trying to run systeminfo command on WIN XP home Turkish 32 bit. And it throw error-

```
'systeminfo' iç ya da dış komut, çalıştırılabilir program ya da toplu iş dosyası olarak tanınmıyor.
```

While this runs fine on English XP. Is there any special command in Turkish to get system information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `systeminfo` program comes with XP *Professional* if I remember correctly (see [here](http://www.computerhope.com/systemin.htm), for example), so I don't think it's related to the fact you have a Turkish edition at all.

Since you have XP *Home,* it doesn't ship with that program, and copying it from a Professional installation may be ... worrisome from a copyright or licensing point of view.

One option is to download the [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) stuff from Microsoft, that contains a great many tools that may be able to give you what you need.